# Enum conforming to protocol with stored property

Tags: swift, enums, swift-protocols

I'm following the [Swift Tour](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html) and they have this example of a protocol

```
protocol ExampleProtocol {
     var simpleDescription: String { get }
     mutating func adjust()
}
```

Then the exercise is

> Write an enumeration that conforms to this protocol.

If I let Xcode stub out the enum, it does this

```
enum SimpleEnum: ExampleProtocol {
    var simpleDescription: String    
    func adjust() {
    }
    case foo
}
```

and then it gives me the error "Enums may not contain stored properties". If I remove the property, it gives me the error "type 'SimpleEnum' does not conform to protocol 'ExampleProtocol'".

I just started learning Swift today so I have no idea what the correct approach is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so the error you are getting is because all properties must be computed.  So, in your simple example, you could do something like this:

```
enum SimpleEnum: ExampleProtocol {
  case foo, bar

  var simpleDescription: String {
     switch self {
       case .foo: return "Foo"
       case .bar: return "Bar"
     }
  } 

  func adjust() {

  }

}
```

Comment: You can also use `return "\(self)"` which will return `foo` or `bar`

Comment: Another example they give is a class implementing the protocol with `var simpleDescription: String = "foo"`. Is that shorthand for a computed property? Because it looks stored to me.

Comment: A class can have stored properties.  Enums can't.  So in a class you can definitely say `var simpleDescription: String = "foo"`.

Answer (score 0):

As the protocol declaration shows, `simpleDescription` should be a computed property that only has a getter, so you should declare `simpleDescription` to be a computed property as well in `SimpleEnum`.

```
enum SimpleEnum: ExampleProtocol {
    var simpleDescription: String {
        return "\(self)"
    }
    func adjust() {
    }
    case foo, bar
}

SimpleEnum.foo.simpleDescription //"foo"
SimpleEnum.bar.simpleDescription //"bar"
```